# Books in Shelf Probability Problem

Tags: probability

The problem is this

> 15 books are put in a horizontal shelf in random order. 5 out of 15 have a case. Student picks random 3 books out of 15. Which is the probability that **at least one** of them would be with case.

I've found the solution of this, which is P(A) = 1 - $\frac{\binom{10}{3}}{\binom{15}{3}}$

Now I am a little bit confused how it would be the solution if it required **all 3 books** are with case(not just at least one of them)

Thanks for your time!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution

Comment: Even without relying on the hypergeometric distribution., you say you found the solution for "at least one"... hopefully that means that you *understand* the solution for "at least one" and you understand that the probability that all 3 books are without a case is $\dfrac{\binom{10}{3}}{\binom{15}{3}}$.  The only difference between that and this is that you swap the roles of the books with cases with the books without cases.

Comment: O thanks, now I got it. Does it equal $\frac{\binom{5}{3}}{\binom{15}{3}}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When 3 books are selected at random from among 15, of which 5 have cases, let $X$ be the number of selected books that have cases. Then $X$ has a **hypergeometric distribution**. Specifically,

$$P(X = k) = \frac{{5 \choose k}{10 \choose 3-k}}{{15 \choose 3}},$$
for $k = 0, 1, 2, 3.$

The computation is easy for such small numbers. (Remember that $0! = 1.)$ You
can check your answers with the numbers shown below.
From R statistical software, here are exact values of the four probabilities (ignore line numbers in []'s):

```
k = 0:3;  PDF = dhyper(k, 5, 10, 3)
cbind(k, PDF)
     k        PDF
[1,] 0 0.26373626
[2,] 1 0.49450549
[3,] 2 0.21978022
[4,] 3 0.02197802

plot(k, PDF, type="h", lwd=2, col="blue",
   ylim=c(0,max(PDF)))
abline(h=0, col="green2")
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe it is worth taking a couple of minutes to install R on your computer. If you only use it for the probability functions, it can be a big help. Free from https://www.r-project.org/ . There are versions for Windows, Mac, and Unix.